# Using row_number() over (partition by) as a subquery in MySQL, conducting an outer join with other tables, no data is returned but "0 row(s) modified"

Tags: sql, mysql, debugging, select, partition

The scenario is as follows:
I need to query the table of active users and retrieve the data for each person ranked first. The SQL statement is provided below.

```
select
    au.id,
    p.user_code,
    au.user_code,
    p.user_code = au.user_code,
    au.row_num 
    -- The original SQL had additional select fields, but they were not important, so I removed them. These few fields were written for testing purposes, and of course, they can be replaced with other fields if needed.
from
    (
    select
        *
    from 
        (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by user_code
        order by
            status ) as row_num
        from
                 
                epm_eval_activity_user sr
        
        )aa
    where
        aa.row_num <= 1
    ) au
inner join epm_user p on
    au.user_code = p.user_code
where
    1 = 1
    and au.user_code = '764451'
```

However, the result is unexpected. The subquery returns data, and the outer user table also contains data.
But when using inner join, no data is returned. To be precise, it returns "0 row(s) modified". It's not an empty table that typically indicates no results. I tried using EXPLAIN, but it also returned "0 row(s) modified".

Then I tried replacing "where au.user_code='xxxx'" with "where p.user_code='xxxx'", and the data was returned correctly. Why is this happening?

And the subquery can retrieve the correct data when executed separately, and it is also confirmed that there is corresponding data in epm_user.

```
-- can retrieve data
    select
        *
    from 
        (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by user_code
        order by
            status ) as row_num
        from
                 
                epm_eval_activity_user sr
        
        )aa
    where
        aa.row_num >= 0
```

Finally, I tried changing the filtering condition to "p.user_code", but even this couldn't explain why the previous SQL query couldn't retrieve the data correctly.

and the mysql version is 8.0.22;

---

This is the DDL statement of the two tables above(Omitted other unrelated fields.). If you are interested, you can try to reproduce this phenomenon yourself.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `epm_eval_activity_user` (
  `id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID',
  `user_code` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'userCode',
  `user_name` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  `status` int DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=prepare,2=fail,3=ok,4=...',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci COMMENT='user eval activity';

-- evaluation.epm_user definition

CREATE TABLE `epm_user` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'id',
  `user_code` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'userCode',
  `user_name` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  `creator` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_tm` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updator` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_tm` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_epm_user_user_code` (`user_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci COMMENT='user';
```

Comment: *To be precise, it returns "updated rows 0".* ?? SELECT updates nothing.. *mysql version is 8.0.22* Use CTE, not subquery.

Comment: @Akina This is the result displayed by DBeaver.

Comment: Also, please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: @NickW its a good suggest

Comment: if DBeaver is making it hard to see the results of `EXPLAIN select ...`, please use the command line client.

Comment: I do note that 8.0.22 is 3 years old, it isn't unreasonable to think this may be a bug fixed since then.

Comment: @Akina it would be nice to know why you suggest a CTE instead of a subquery?  is that for style reasons or because you expect it to fix a problem?

Comment: @ysth Are epm_eval_activity_user.user_code and epm_user.user_code the same data type? Could be something going on with implicit conversion

Comment: @ysth Clear query text makes the searching of the problem source more easy. Do this - and you'll see that the query is extremely strange itself - 4 of 5 output columns are constants.. PS. I think that we see a result of over-optimization. Window functions are evaluated over the output rowset, but the optimizer may convert the query into plain form which will result in `WHERE aa.row_num <= 1` is always FALSE. AFAIR I have seen similar topics already..

Comment: @Akina The original SQL was not like this. I made these changes just to remove other unnecessary fields and compare the query results of the AU table and P table.

Comment: @Error_2646 yes, they are same data type, varchar(120)

Comment: *The original SQL was not like this.* Does the first query is one which you need in? Look - in the subquery for each `user_code` you prepare the selection of the row with the least `status` (see further `where aa.row_num <= 1`), but you select the row for one definite user (further `where au.user_code = '764451'`). So you may simply select this one row using `where user_code = '764451' ORDER BY status LIMIT 1` in the subquery.

Comment: @Akina Yes, the original SQL was more complex than this one. However, when I discovered this issue, I tried to reproduce it in a test environment using simplified SQL, including filtering by user_code and selecting specific fields.